# How to fix "Invalid class string (MS Visual Database Tools)" when creating new Database Diagrams in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a new database diagram in SQL Server 2008 R2, but I get this message:

> [Invalid class string (MS Visual Database Tools)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Du6.png)

Before that, I have deleted SQL Server 2008 R2 and reinstalled it. And after I have that error, I reinstall it once again but it did not fix. I've been searching for answers on google and I still can't find any solution either. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

> Details:
>
> Invalid class string
>   (MS Visual Database Tools)
>
> Program Location:
>
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.NativeMethods.ThrowOnFailure(Int32 hr)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateDesigner(DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, Urn parentUrn, IManagedConnection mc, String fileName)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.CreateDesignerWindow(IManagedConnection mc, DocumentOptions options)

PS: sorry for my bad English

Comment: Database diagrams are not a feature of SQL Server (despite being stored in the database), they are strictly a feature of SQL Server Management Studio. A simple workaround for potential problems with that would be to install a more recent version (preferably on a separate client machine), since newer versions are backwards compatible. The latest versions can be [downloaded as standalone applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms). Use the 17.x branch, the 18.x branch doesn't support database diagrams.

Comment: Thanks so much, I updated to SQL Server 2012 and it worked :D